How to update a label control in Spotfire with a matched data table column value when a drop-down filter control changes?
I have a Spotfire data table that looks like this:



site_id
site_name




ABC123
Site Name 1


DEF456
Site Name 2


GHI789
Site Name 3


...
...



There are about 1,500 rows in this data table. I also have a drop-down filter in a text area that is linked to the "site_id" column above via a document property, and I have the report working nicely where a user can select the "site_id" of interest from the drop-down and it will update the visual below it. However I want the user to be able to also see the "site_name" of the ID they have chosen so they can ensure it is the correct location. I figured the best way to do this would be to have a label control next to the drop-down that looks up the matching "site_name" when the "site_id" drop-down changes.
I tried using cascading drop-downs which kind of worked, but the 2nd control also has to be a drop-down and you need to choose the "site_name" yourself.
I have also tried using a variety of IronPython statements but I could not get it working to link to the "site_name" column.
I know I could potentially concatenate the columns and have the one drop-down control for everything, but some of the site names are long and would run in to formatting issues with the drop-down.
Is Spotfire capable of doing this? I am working in Spotfire Analyst v11.4.2.

If would be easier, if it works for you, to create a calculated column:
concatenate([site_id],' (',[site_name],')')

and let the user select from that on the drop-down list.

Yes, this was the fall-back option. I was mainly checking to see if it could be done in Spotfire, and it sounds like it can but I'm getting the impression that it may not be straightforward. No problem, I will use this simpler method. Thanks!
